# How can I resize my image?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-resizing

This is my image uploading and resizing code in codeigniter.But in my client's server the image is uploaded but not create a resized image into a folder

```
if($imgwidth >= 1025 && $imgheight >= 650)
        {
            $epld=explode('.',$ex);
            $filename=date("mdyHis").".".$epld[1];
            $uploaddir = './bg_images/'; 
            $file = $uploaddir . basename($filename); 

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"./bg_images/".$filename))
            {

                $this->load->library('image_lib');
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $file ;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                $this->md_image->resize_image('./bg_images/'.$filename,1025,650,'./bg_images/thumbs/'.$filename);

            }
        }
```

The bg_images is the folder name and the md_image is the library used for resizing

Comment: any errors or anything? are the permissions on the bg_images folder ok? does gd2 exist there?

Comment: how can i check gd2 is allowed in it? no errors displayed.

Comment: Just make a php file containing `<?php phpinfo()` and visit it in a browser. This will list everything PHP supports on that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not spot any errors in your code.
Make sure you have gdlib installed by uploading a script with the following content:

```
<?php
    echo phpinfo();
?>
```

The Script shows your php configuration.
Search for "gd" with your browser's search function. No mention of "gd" would mean that you are missing this library, but you need it for image manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

does the `./bg_images/thumbs/` folder exist on the file system?

As far as I remember, gdlib would not create folder itself. If the folder is missing, create it yourself (remember to give it the right permissions, the server / php process needs write permission (most likely www-data))

If all this doesn't help, ask your client's admin for access to the error logs.